# Problem converting a saved_model.pb file to .tflite file with custom shapes

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am using Tensorflow 2 on Windows 10 and I download a model from [TensorFlow Detection Model Zoo.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)

The model I am using is **ssd.mobilenetv2.oid4**

The model details are:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'image_tensor:0' shape=(None, None, None, 3) dtype=uint8>]
```

Note: I also have the frozen_inference_graph.pb available along with config file and checkpoint.

I used the TensorFlowLiteConverter Snippet to convert a saved_model.pb file to .tflite with custom shape:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_dir = "D:\\Models\\ssd_mobilenet_v2_oid_v4_2018_12_12\\saved_model"

model = tf.saved_model.load(input_dir)
concrete_func = model.signatures[
tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
concrete_func.inputs[0].set_shape([None, None, None, 3])
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bhavin\Desktop\TensorFlow_pb_converter.py", line 10, in <module>
tflite_model = converter.convert()
File "C:\Users\Bhavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\lite\python\lite.py", line 428, in convert
"invalid shape '{1}'.".format(_get_tensor_name(tensor), shape_list))
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'
```

I tried using toco and tflite_convert but I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong and how do I convert this pb file to tflite file?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have the same need.@Renegade

Answer (score 0):

Currently tensorflow Lite doesn't support converting dynamic shape except for first dimension.
Consider setting the exact shape instead of 'None'

Comment: I set the size as 1,300,300,3, the error got solved but then I got datatype error. The datatype of the model is UINT8, but the error states that the code requires FLOAT. I checked the internet but I didn't get any examples for trying to convert the model to tflite with specific datatype using python.

Comment: You might be missing setting the input type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/lite/TFLiteConverter

Comment: Is that all right now? I only have one dynamic shape's saved_model.pb. How to conver it to a `.tflite` file?@KarimNosseir

Comment: TFLite now supports dynamic shape inputs. Follow the guide https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert#python_api

Did you try and something failed ?

It is preferred to use saved model format for converting to TFLite file